# How do I sum the total calculated values in a loop (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to sum the total yearly rent for the period, using the code shown below.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
rent_rate = input('please enter the price per square foot:')   # price sq/ft
lease_rate = input('please enter the rate of the lease:')           # interest rate
lease_term = input('please enter the tenor (in years) of the lease:')  
size_of_space = input('please enter the size(in square feet) of the space:')  

print "Year %25s" % "Rent Rate%25s"  % "Rate%25s" % "Square Feet%25s" % "Yearly Rent%25s" % "Monthly Rent"


for year in range( 0, lease_term ):
   rent_rate = principal * ( 1.0 + rate ) ** year
   yearly_rent = rent_rate * size_of_space
   monthly_rent = yearly_rent/12
   print "%4d%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f" % ( year + 1, rent_rate, rate, size_of_space, yearly_rent, monthly_rent)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Provide your input and desired output

Comment: Please, dont do `print "Year %25s" % "Rent Rate%25s"  % "Rate%25s" % "Square Feet%25s" % "Yearly Rent%25s" % "Monthly Rent"`, use comma seperators or the + operator or any other reccomended way of joining strings.

Comment: You are reading `rent_rate` from `stdin` then overwriting it on the first line of the loop, and where are `principle` and `rate` coming from?  Anything read from `input()` needs to be converted to a numeric before you use it in a calculation, `int()` or `float()`.  For example:  `range(0, int(lease_term))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a few things! You should assign 'principal' as well as 'rent_rate' to something because they came out of thin air!

Also, if the user inputs are going to numbers, you should do 'int' or 'float' of those inputs! Here:

```
rent_rate = float(input('please enter the price per square foot:'))   
lease_rate = float(input('please enter the rate of the lease:'))       
lease_term = int(input('please enter the tenor (in years) of the lease:'))  
size_of_space = float(input('please enter the size(in square feet) of the space:'))  

print "Year %25s" % "Rent Rate%25s"  % "Rate%25s" % "Square Feet%25s" %  "Yearly Rent%25s" % "Monthly Rent"


for year in range(0, lease_term):
   rent_rate = principal * ( 1.0 + rate ) ** year
   yearly_rent = rent_rate * size_of_space
   monthly_rent = yearly_rent/12
   print "%4d%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f%21.2f" % ( year + 1, rent_rate, rate,     size_of_space, yearly_rent, monthly_rent)
```

And just as a style thing--the in-line comments should be done sparingly. Check out the python Pep 8 Style Guide!